# Running R in the background

Tags: r, ssh, igraph, ubuntu-15.04

Hi this is a question which i am not sure how to frame.

I am running R from a remote server. My access to the remote server is via ssh@username and so on. After i access i have a command prompt which i invoke R and i am comfortable working on R.

Question 1
I have a large network (100k nodes) and would like to do community detection and would like to run it in the background such that if i close my terminal its keeps running until its finished saves the result in my R working directory.

I have tried using nohup R &  but i am not sure the process completed successful.

Question 2
If i manage to implement Question 1, how could i continue to use R to perform other task? and

Question 3
How do i check the task in Q1 is still running.

my attempt on a script looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
library(igraph)
library(data.table)
edgebetween <- function(x) {
  simplify(x, remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T) 
   edge.betweenness.community(x, directed = T)
}
community.a.g3 <- edgebetween(a.g3)
```

i have saved the script in my working director as a.R

and used at the command prompt after changing to my working directory
     chmod +x a.R
     nohup  ./a.R &

What would i need to correct. Thanks

Comment: Check out screen (https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). It allows you to check in and out of a terminal session without ending it, allowing it to continue even after you disconnect.

Comment: Also, you can have multiple screen sessions at a time. Each can have its own session of R open.

Comment: Forget `screen`, and let it retire. Use [**`tmux`**](https://tmux.github.io/), a modern replacement.

Answer (score 10):

You want to execute R in "batch" mode. See ( https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/BATCH.html )

The command below is an example from those docs. The "&" says "run this separate from the user's login session" so when you log out, it continues to run.

```
R CMD BATCH [options] infile [outfile] &
```

You can also use nohup as discussed here ( http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/wiki/index.php/Running_Jobs_in_the_Background )

```
nohup R CMD BATCH ./myprog.R &
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but if other needs an answer.
Do this:
Save your script, I'll use Test.R as example.

```
head Test.R
library(igraph)
library(data.table)
edgebetween <- function(x) {
  simplify(x, remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T) 
   edge.betweenness.community(x, directed = T)
}
community.a.g3 <- edgebetween(a.g3)
```

use `screen` then run `Rscript Test.R` and hit `ctrl + a + d`.
when you come back do `screen -ls`, and then `screen -r <Number of your screen session>`. Voila!