# `nohup` on EC2: running R script from the terminal

Tags: r, amazon-web-services

I am trying to run an R script from the terminal on an EC2 AWS Instance.

I run the following: `nohup R Rfiles/MyRscript.R`

With the terminal command line:

`rstudio@ip-10-0-0-8:~/Dropbox/Folder$ nohup R Rfiles/MyRscript.R`

My `nohup.out` file says:

```
ARGUMENT 'Rfiles/MyRscript.R' __ignored__

Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla'
```

I tried adding `--save` etc. without any progress so I assume I am going wrong with trying to call the `R` script using `nohup`.

My question is how can I run correctly the R script using `nohup` so that I can leave it running and log out.

EDIT:

I tried this but got the error: `ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'`

```
nohup R CMD BATCH ./Rscript.R &
```

EDIT 2:

This seems to be working, however I am not exactly sure what I am creating/done

```
nohup R CMD BATCH ./MYR_SCRIPT.R </dev/null >nohup.out 2>nohup.err
```

Answer (score 0):

the syntax for this would be

```
R CMD BATCH [options] infile [outfile] &
```

or

```
nohup R CMD BATCH ./myprog.R &
```

but as you stated you already tried this.

The following has some useful information:
[Running R in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171338/running-r-in-the-background)
along with this https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/BATCH.html

are you perhaps adding the arguments in the wrong place?

```
nohup R CMD BATCH --save ./myprog.R &
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working for me `nohup R CMD BATCH ./R_scripts_location/MYR_Script.R </dev/null >nohup_RScript.out 2>nohup_RScript.err &`