# Preload R package when start program

Tags: python, r

I just begin with R.
Usually I worked on Python but 1 step on my program require to run the Rscript, the package I loaded on that script takes a lot of time and it is reloaded everytime I run a new session on my python program. Does anyway for me to preload it when I start the python script so I don't need to reload all R packages on the script for the next running of the program?
p/s: my program is on Windows and I run the R script through subprocess.call('path/to/Rscript.exe path/to/R script.R --some augments')

Comment: with each subprocess.call(), you are calling R as a whole new session. That's why on each runtime, it will preload everything as if you are just starting a new R session.

Comment: thanks, so is there any alternative methods I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: try look into `tmux` or `nohup` command call; it may allow R session to be kept alive. Also checkout r support article on that too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171338/running-r-in-the-background